# Javascript text printing order

Tags: javascript

Just beginning to learn JavaScript, have written below simple code to print out text and testing it in Browser.

the output is :

> This is from a javascript function...
>
> This is my test heading

But I was trying to change the order(swap the two sentences printed) of the sentences being printed to:

> This is my test heading
>
> This is from a javascript function...

What changes are needed in the below code to print the text printed in above order.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

<p id="demo">This is a paragraph.</p>
<p id = "demo1">This is demo1.</p>

</body>

<script>
//document.write("<h3>This is my test heading</h3>");
document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML="This is my test heading";
</script>

<script>

//alert("My First JavaScript");

displaytext();

function displaytext()
{
    
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="This is from a javascript function...";
    
}

</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Switch the IDs. `This is from a javascipt function...` appears first because the element `demo` is before the element `demo1`. This has nothing to do with the execution order.

Comment: @Felix Kling. Thanks pls .put your comment as answer , so i can accept.

Comment: What wrong in this question? Downvoters, and those voting to close, do comment with your explanations pls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HTML, the order of JavaScript functions doesn't matter as much as the order in which you have put your HTML Elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/3CpU7/

The above fiddle has your answer: you have to switch the DIVs.

```
<p id = "demo1">This is demo1.</p>
<p id="demo">This is a paragraph.</p>
```

Also, keep in mind - You can use CSS to create whatever behaviour you want for DIVs  (e.g. float, clear, position, etc.)

**EDIT:**

What also is another obvious way to do it is, if you don't want to change your HTML Markup, is interchange the content of the DIVs as this:
(Another fiddle for this: http://jsfiddle.net/3CpU7/1/)

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="This is my test heading";
displaytext();

function displaytext()
{

    document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML="This is from a javascript function...";

}
```

Hope it helps your initial learning. :)

Answer (score -4):

Switch the HTML element's `id`. As the function name implies, the `getElementById` function gets you the HTML element with the given id (if exists, else `null`).

This

```
document.getElementById("demo1")
```

refers to

```
<p id="demo1">This is a paragraph.</p>
```

And

```
document.getElementById("demo")
```

refers to

```
<p id="demo">This is demo1.</p>
```

Since the elements in your HTML are in the order

```
<p id="demo1">This is a paragraph.</p>
<p id="demo">This is demo1.</p>
```

you must target `demo1` to change the first and `demo` to change the second paragraph's inner HTML.

Thus, either change the ids in your JS function call, or in your HTML.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById

Comment: Where's the answer? This seems to be a game of spot-the-difference

Comment: It'd be nice to actually explain what you've done instead of pasting and changing one minor thing. @Quentin couldn't have said it any better.

Comment: Point noted. Added an actual answer.